# Paypal post to C# REST API endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, .net-core

In my front end, I have this piece of code that should call the API post endpoint:

```
... 
onAuthorize(_data: any, actions: any) {
actions.request.post('https://localhost:44353/api/payment',_data)
    .then...
```

API endpoint looks like this

```
[ProducesResponseType(201)]
[HttpPost("payment")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Payment([FromBody] PaypalDTO paypal){...
```

But the API call returns: bad request/bad format..

Currently the only way to pass data that I found is through query params..

But I bet there is a way to format the REST API Endpoint to get the _data object.

Ideas?

Comment: Show `PaypalDTO` and also how the model is prepared and sent from the client.

Comment: So what does your body look like in the final request? What does your PaypalDTO look like?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, can you control your json data ? And secondly can you add Content-Type your request ?

Finally maybe this link helps to you

[Official Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)